# About the Wedderburn-Malcev Theorem

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

The Wedderburn-Malcev theorem states that for every (associative unital) finite-dimensional algebra $A$ over field $F$, there exist a semisimple subalgebra $S$, such that $A=\mathrm{Rad}(A)\oplus S$ as a vector space, where $\mathrm{Rad}(A)$ is the Jacobson radical of $A$.

Can someone help me about the structure of subalgebra $S$? I mean I know the existence of of such $S$, is it possible to understand how it is constructed and what is its relation with $A$?

Comment: I think $A/rad(A)$ has to be separable.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sek/select/RF6.pdf), the part you cite is still due to Wedderburn. Malcev's contribution was to show that any semisimple $S'$ such that $A = Rad(A) \oplus S'$ must be conjugate to $S$ by an element of the form $(1+r)$ for $r \in Rad(A)$.

Answer (score 5):

> $S \cong A/rad(A)$ as $F$-algebra.

Proof: The composition $S \hookrightarrow A \twoheadrightarrow A/rad(A)$ is a surjective $F$-algebra homomorphism with kernel $S \cap rad(A)=0$.

By Wedderburn's theorem we also know $A/rad(A) \cong \prod_{i=1}^m M_{n_i}(D_i)$ where $D_i$ is a division algebra over $F$.

Answer (score 0):

I have also asked this question and partially answered within my diploma thesis (Separabilität in kommutativen und auflösbaren Algebren. Unter Berücksichtigung nicht-unitärer assoziativer Algebren).